# Parse the paragraph into different strings using JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

How can I extract the rest of the PARAGRAPHS, except the image in the below string in java ?

I am able to get the mage link, however I am stuck with the Ps.

```
<img width="300" height="246" src="http://something.mything.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/ray-300x246.jpg" class="attachment-medium wp-post-image" alt="rayi_slleiman_bkerke" style="float: right; margin-left: 5px;" />
<p>
<strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the priectronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
 <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the priectronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Comment: Please post your code so far.

Comment: could you please show your java code too?

Comment: String content = aboveString.replaceAll("<img.+>", ""); -- but it erases everything, I want to show the rest of the html other than the image tag.

Comment: Have you solved this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String html = "<img width='300' height='246' src='http://mesrobian.sarnok.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/rayi_slleiman_bkerke-300x246.jpg'" +
                " class='attachment-medium wp-post-image' alt='rayi_slleiman_bkerke' style='float: right; margin-left: 5px;' /><p><strong>Lorem Ip" +
                "sum</strong> is simply dummy text of the priectronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960" +
                "s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Al" +
                "dus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the priectronic type" +
                "setting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ip" +
                "sum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");      
        System.out.println(paragraphs);
```

Will output:

```
<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the priectronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the priectronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```